# Why is my method Render Props of the React Component not working?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem. I'm trying do the method Render Prop but it not is working.

My project is: It has to render some names of `ComponentDidMount`, and I can get it to do the filter and to filter the names. But I passed the function `filter` for a component, and do the `Render Prop`.

I pass it here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Body.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import Filter from './Filter';

class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employee: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));
  }

  getName = (filter) => {
    const { employee, add } = this.state;
    return employee.filter(employee => employee.name.includes(filter)).map(name => (
      <div className='item' key={name.id}>
        <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.id}`}>
          <div key={name.id}>
            <img className="img" alt="imgstatic"
              src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.id}`}
            />
          </div>
          <h1 className="name2"> {name.name} </h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ));
  };


  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4 className="manager"> Hello {this.props.currentManager}, here be all employees available for change. </h4>
        <div className="body">
          {this.getName()}
        </div>
        <div className='input'>
          <Filter render={this.getName} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Body;
```

And here I get him:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      input: ''
    }
  }

  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
    console.log();

    console.log(this.state.input)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input placeholder='Search name here' type="text" onChange={this.getValueInput} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Filter
```

But something's not working...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not at all using the render prop being supplied to the Filter component. Also the objective of render prop is to render the data, go using `this.getName()` inside the render Body Component isn't correct either(for one you are not passing the filter value to the getName). You would use it like

```
import React from 'react';
import './Body.css';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';
import Filter from './Filter';

class Body extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      employee: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:3004/employee")
      .then(response => this.setState({ employee: response.data }));
  }

  getName = (filter) => {
    const { employee, add } = this.state;
    return employee.filter(employee => employee.name.includes(filter)).map(name => (
      <div className='item' key={name.id}>
        <Link className="link" to={`/user/${name.id}`}>
          <div key={name.id}>
            <img className="img" alt="imgstatic"
              src={`https://picsum.photos/${name.id}`}
            />
          </div>
          <h1 className="name2"> {name.name} </h1>
        </Link>
      </div>
    ));
  };


  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4 className="manager"> Hello {this.props.currentManager}, here be all employees available for change. </h4>
        <div className='body'>
          <Filter render={this.getName} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Body;
```

and Filter as

```
import React from 'react';

class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      input: ''
    }
  }

  getValueInput = (evt) => {
    const inputValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({ input: inputValue });
    console.log();

    console.log(this.state.input)
  }


  render() {
    return ( 
      <React.Fragment>
          {this.props.render(this.state.input)}
          <div className='input'>
            <input placeholder='Search name here' type="text" onChange={this.getValueInput} />
          </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Note `React.Fragment` is available from v16.2.0 onwards and if you are not using the relevant version replace `React.Fragment` with `<div>`